# How do you get SwiftUI Previews to work when Codegen is in ClassDefinition or Category/Extension?

Tags: core-data, swiftui

I have a view using core data and xcdatamodeld file that contains the definition for an `Item` struct. If I use Xcode to generate the files for `Item` and manually manage them, preview works fine. However, when I use Codegen in either of the other formations, I get errors saying that the entire struct is undefined. This prevents the previews from working.

Code:

```
struct ArchiveView: View {
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    @FetchRequest(entity: Item.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var fetchedResults: FetchedResults<Item>
    
    var body: some View {
        return NavigationView {
            List(fetchedResults, id: \.self ) { (fetchedResult: Item) in
                return PurchaseView(name: fetchedResults.name price: fetchedResults.price, purchaseDate: fetchedResults.date)
            }
        }.navigationBarTitle("Order")
    }
}
```

Both the Item+CoreDataClass and Item+CoreDataProperties are missing since they are automatically generated by xcode.

I am now using manual Codegen to be able to see the previews, but am curious whether I could use the other options. How can I use Class Defintion Codegen for the core data files and still be able to use SwiftUI previews?

Answer (score 0):

After some testing, something appears to be wrong with the xcode code generator itself. Whenever I change the code generator to anything other than Class Definition at least once, this breaks the linking with previews.

The fix was to create a new project and copy over the old files.